# Selenium and :hover css

Tags: css, testing, selenium, hover, selenium-rc

Using selenium-rc and the java client, I want to test a menu which opens when the user moves the mouse over it. It closes when the mouse leaves the menu. This is done using `:hover` css, without any javascript.

In selenium, there are many methods for mouse actions, but none of them seems to trigger any css `:hover` style to be used.

Google shows that I am not alone with this problem, but there has not be a solution. Some folks comment that you had to add some javascript code; however, in selenium rc, I don't think that I even have a proper place for user-contributed additional javascript code.

My wish would be the following code to work, given that a div#navi_settings contained the menu which contains the - normally invisible - a element:

```
selenium.mouseHover("css=div#navi_settings");
assertTrue(selenium.isVisible("//a[contains(text(), 'Text on link')]"));
```

Unfortunately, the method `moveHover()` does not yet exist.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: By manually testing this :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do this using the Selenium interface. However, since I am using Selenium 2, I can use the WebDriver API, as per http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/msg/8210537dde07155f?pli=1

In your case, something like this may work, if you can upgrade to Selenium 2:

```
WebDriver webDriver; 
...
((RenderedWebElement) webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#navi_settings"))).hover();
```

Comment: This works on platforms that have Selenium native events support (Linux and Windows). On Mac, you are out of luck currently: https://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/c08444af61cc2898

Answer (score -1):

The [mouseOver](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html) method will activate a `:hover` pseudoclass.

Comment: Since when? In selenium server v2.0 [a2], with Core v2.0 [a2], this did not work, at least with firefox 3.5.

Comment: Then use some javascript to make the menu visible when you need to click one of its elements.  That's what I ended up doing, and it worked fine.  Or try asking your question on the Selenium mailing list.

Comment: mailing list: ok, your point, but the menu visibility is css driven which is working well. Testing clicks on menu items is not the problem. I am testing the *visibility itself* when the user hovers over the menu. Changing the application to use javascript instead of css is out of the question.