# Selenium - Clicking on a hidden button that appears only when hovering above it

Tags: java, junit, selenium, webdriver

I am attempting to run some automated tests in Eclipse using Java (running them as JUnit tests) and I'm using Selenium IDE 1.0.10 plugin for Firefox in order to find the button IDs. The problem is that on the webpage, I have a hidden button on a row that becomes visible only when hovering above it. If I click on the button, Selenium registers the click, but if I attempt to run the test case, it stops at that click, since the button is only visible when the mouse hovers over it. Is there a way, a command in Selenium for "mouse hover" or something that makes the button visible before clicking it? If you need more information, please ask and I will provide everything I can. I don't know what else is needed since I'm pretty new at both Java and Selenium.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium and :hover css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973145/selenium-and-hover-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

selenium.mouseOver("mylocator");

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't get it to work. I use mouseOver command in the Selenium plugin, enter the correct element (as far as I can tell, anyway), yet nothing happens when I run the test. It doesn't fail because the element I mouseOver is present, yet the hidden buttons do not appear. Again, I'm sorry if I'm not more explicit.

Comment: Are you sure it's a hover that is activating the hidden buttons?  Can you provide the HTML and associated JavaScript of the element?