# selenium Mosue Over not working if hover property is defined in CSS

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Selenium is not able to perform mouseOver if Hover property is defined in CSS

You can try yourself on this link using selenium ide
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more2

Selenium mouse Over has no effect on this link

please visit this link

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973145/selenium-and-hover-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium and :hover css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973145/selenium-and-hover-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question, this is one of those perennial problems [Selenium and :hover css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973145/selenium-and-hover-css)

They discuss a couple of solutions, but it looks like the problem is that as Javascript cannot trigger the :hover pseudo class, so Selenium can't either.